# Why is CiviCRM mistranslating my string?

Tags: i18n

My site is translating Yes to Si for French (fr_FR). I've confirmed that:

1. I don't have any word replacments for Yes.
2. Most everything else is translated correctly.
3. I've got an up-to-date civicrm.po file for fr_FR and it contains the correct translation of "Oui".

I've even installed the brilliant de.systopia.l10nmo and org.civicrm.l10nx extensions and uploaded an override .mo file.

WTF?

Answer (score 1):

In the file /CRM/Core/BAO/WordReplacement.php you've got this delightful stanza:

```
// So. Weird. Some bizarre/probably-broken multi-lingual thing where
// data isn't really stored in civicrm_word_replacements. Probably
// shouldn't exist.
$stringOverride = self::_getLocaleCustomStrings($id);
$stringOverride[$config->lcMessages] = $overrides;
```

And digging in, you'll see it does this:

```
$domain = CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery('SELECT locale_custom_strings FROM civicrm_domain WHERE id = %1', [
  1 => [$domainId, 'Integer'],
]);
```

In other words, it's pulling word replacement information from a field in the civicrm_domain file which is no longer accessible or used in the UI.

I looked in there and sure enough, I had an old collection of translations. By setting the field to empty, it solved the problem.

Comment: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2085